# Unable to delete Trace in Eagle

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

After running the design through the Errors Tool and moving a route that had insufficient clearance, I'm left with this blue segment that is overlaying the red route.

Why is it there and how can it be removed?

[image]

[image]

Another unwanted blue segment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not actually a trace. That's a graphical artifact left behind by the Design Rule Check showing you where the problem was. Run the DRC again and it'll disappear (assuming you've corrected the violation that the DRC found in the first place).